# Log4j 2 lambda "lazy logging"

Tags: java, logging, lambda, log4j, log4j2

The [Log4j 2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/api.html) gives an example of how to use lambdas for "lazy logging":

```
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```

It also gives an example of how to use format parameters to avoid unnecessary string concatenation:

```
logger.debug("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar());
```

My question: Can I gain the same performance benefits by simply supplying one lambda with a normal string concatenation approach?

```
logger.trace(() -> "Concatting " + user.getName() + " with " + expensiveOperation());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most performant in your example would be

```
logger.trace("Concatting {} with {}", () -> user.getName(), () -> expensiveOperation());
```

This way

1. Neither of the methods is called unless the debug level is TRACE
2. No String objects are created: Log4j2 uses a threadlocal StringBuilder under the hood to be garbage free
3. You avoid allocating a temporary StringBuilder for String concatenation (what Java does under the hood when you "+" two Strings)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Log4J2 in garbage-free mode, your last code sample is the way to go.

> ```java
> logger.trace(() -> "Concatting " + user.getName() + " with " + expensiveOperation());
> ```

Quoting from Log4J2 [Garbage-free Steady State Logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/garbagefree.html) page, as of 2023-11-01:

> **Note:** not all logging is garbage free. Specifically:
>
> - Logging a lambda *as a parameter* (`logger.info("lambda value is {}", () -> callExpensiveMethod())`) creates a vararg array. Logging a lambda expression by itself is garbage-free: `logger.debug(() -> callExpensiveMethod())`.